# Pandas Dataframe to String with separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, utf-8, tostring

I want to turn a dataframe into a string.
this topic [How to turn a pandas dataframe row into a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877708/how-to-turn-a-pandas-dataframe-row-into-a-comma-separated-string) is close to what I want. The only problem of this solution : I have a column 'Country' with string which have separator (for example, with this solution, the dataframe is converting into string but I have 'United States' that become 'United,States')
So currently I just have the following code:

```
df = df.to_string(index=False).split('\n')
df = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df]
df = '\r\n'.join(df)
df = df.encode('utf8')
```

but for a dataframe like this one:

```
data = [['United States', 10, 12], ['United Kingdom', 15, 25], ['France', 14, 18]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country', 'Number1', 'Number2'])
```

I will have

```
b'Country,Number1,Number2\r\nUnited,States,10,12\r\n,United,Kingdom,15,25\r\nFrance,14,18'
```

Instead of:

```
b'Country,Number1,Number2\r\nUnited States,10,12\r\n,United Kingdom,15,25\r\nFrance,14,18'
```

Currently I have solved the problem by many :

```
df= df.replace('United,States', 'United States')
```

But it is not a really good solution because each times a new country with space come, I have to update the script

(the final goal is to convert dataframe into string in utf-8 to be allow to compute it's md5 , without using df.to_csv() and compute the md5 of the file created, if you have a better way than this trick it can also help me)
Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between `I will have` text and `instead of` text? I can not notice any difference?

Comment: it is the space in 'United States', with a comma in what I have (because of the ','.join(), there is no difference between space into a column and space that separate column)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data = [['United States', 10, 12], ['United Kingdom', 15, 25], ['France', 14, 18]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country', 'Number1', 'Number2'])

df = df.to_csv(header=None, index=False).strip('\n').split('\n')
df_string = '\r\n'.join(df)  # <= this is the string that you can use with md5
df_bytes = df_string.encode('utf8')  # <= this is bytes object to write the file
print(df_bytes)
```

Use `df_string` for **md5** and `df_bytes` to write the file.

`df_bytes` contains this:

`b'United States,10,12\r\nUnited Kingdom,15,25\r\nFrance,14,18'`

Comment: It works greate thanks! I didn't know the trick df = df.to_csv()

Answer (score 1):

Variant without sending it to csv:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['United States', 10, 12], ['United Kingdom', 15, 25], ['France', 14, 18]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country', 'Number1', 'Number2']) 

df['Country']=df['Country'].str.replace(' ','_')
df = df.to_string(index=False).split('\n')
df = [','.join(ele.split()) for ele in df]
df = [element.replace('_',' ') for element in df]
df = '\r\n'.join(df)
df = df.encode('utf8')
df
```

Comment: It works also, but I'll keep Roman answer because comparing the two, the function to_string is very slow : on my side, it takes 13.5 second only for this line when Roman entire Solution takes 0.03 seconds